# `make check` for glibc fails with "libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work"

Tags: linux, makefile, pthreads, glibc

While building `glibc` some test files generate this error message:

> `libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work`

The current Google search results do not really make sense to me. Any idea how t fix it?

**UPDATE**:

*gcc Version:*

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.3_source/configure --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)
```

*Linux kernel:*

```
Linux version 3.0.101-0.15-default (geeko@buildhost)
(gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1
SMP Wed Jan 22 15:49:03 UTC 2014 (5c01f4e)
```

*OS:*

```
Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l).
```

**UPDATE**

According to the comment from Etan Reisner I add the full command which fails. I would say that with the `env` command the correct and new built libraries should be used:

```
env GCONV_PATH=/builds/glibc-2.22_build/iconvdata 
  LOCPATH=/builds/glibc-2.22_build/localedata LC_ALL=C 
  /builds/glibc-2.22_build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
  --library-path /builds/glibc-2.22_build:
    /builds/glibc-2.22_build/math:
    /builds/glibc-2.22_build/elf:/builds/glibc-2.22_build/dlfcn:
    /builds/glibc-2.22_build/nss:/builds/glibc-2.22_build/nis:
    /builds/glibc-2.22_build/rt:/builds/glibc-2.22_build/resolv:
    /builds/glibc-2.22_build/crypt:/builds/glibc-2.22_build/mathvec:
    /builds/glibc-2.22_build/nptl /builds/glibc-2.22_build/nptl/tst-robustpi2  
   > /builds/glibc-2.22_build/nptl/tst-robustpi2.out; 
   ../scripts/evaluate-test.sh nptl/tst-robustpi2 $? false false
```

**UPDATE**:

Result when running the `ldd` command for the test file which fails:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd07ff000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f511320a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5112e92000)
    /usr/local/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f5113465000)
```

Here the result for a test file which works:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff68fff000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd09741f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd0970a7000)
    /usr/local/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fd09767a000)
```

And now here is the problem: The path `/usr/local/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` does not exist at all!

Comment: Which OS do you use ?

Comment: Did you try to install the `libgcc` package ?

Comment: @Piere According to `SLES yast` the `libgcc 4.6.9` is installed. The only `libgcc` download site I could find is this: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libgcc but this is for Fedora Distribution. I am not sure I can use it.

Comment: I'm going to assume what that means is that the version of `libgcc_s.so.1` you are *currently building* must be installed for `pthread_cancel` (and thus the tests that use it) to work. So, because your system is using a *different* `glibc` version, the tests are being skipped.

Comment: `env` only modifies the environment of the command being run in the ways specified. So that command will set `GCONV_PATH`, `LOCPATH` and `LC_ALL` in the environment of `/builds/glibc-2.22_build/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` when running it but leave the rest of the environment intact. And the environment may or may not have anything to do with this. I don't know. I could be wrong about my assumption but that's what it (naively) looks like to me. Google seems to think the issue may be a 32bit library issue.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, I read it also regarding the 32bit issue. I updated now again the question with the result of `ldd` for a test file which works and which does not work. Apart from the address all is the same...